# What does Tiresias's answer to the gods mean?

Tags: greek, zeus, hera, love

Zeus and Hera once had an argument on which gender enjoyed love making more. They called on Tiresias, a mortal that had been both a man and a woman. his answer was this...

> Of ten parts a man enjoys one only, but a woman enjoys the full ten parts in her heart.

What does this mean? What are the ten parts?

Answer (score 5):

This is from Appolodorus 3.6.7. It does not refer to specific parts or phases of intercourse. You should read the numbers as percentages, as the translation indicates:

> Hence, when Hera and Zeus disputed whether the pleasures of love are
>   felt more by women or by men, they referred to him for a decision. He
>   said that if the pleasures of love **be reckoned at ten**, men enjoy one
>   and women nine. Wherefore Hera blinded him, but Zeus bestowed on him
>   the art of soothsaying. The saying of Tiresias to Zeus and Hera: "Of
>   ten parts a man enjoys one only; but a woman enjoys the full ten parts
>   in her heart."

In the original text, the saying reads:

> τὸ ὑπὸ Τειρεσίου λεχθὲν πρὸς Δία καὶ Ἥραν·
>   οἴην μὲν μοῖραν δέκα μοιρῶν τέρπεται ἀνήρ,
>   τὰς δὲ δέκ' ἐμπίπλησι γυνὴ τέρπουσα νόημα.